# Multiplication of inverse and non-inverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have thought about the combination of multiplication product of invertible and non-invertible matrices:

invertible $\cdot$ invertible = invertible

non-invertible $\cdot$non-invertible = non-invertible

non-invertible $\cdot$invertible = non-invertible

invertible $\cdot$non-invertible = non-invertible

Is it right? I have thought about from the point of view that non-invertible matrix is row equivalent to a matrix with a zero row there for multiple it from both right and left will produce a matrix with a zero row and a zero column respectfully, and opposite goes for invertible matrices

Comment: You should replace "inverse" with "invertible". Then it is all right.

Comment: Yes, the product $AB$, where either $A$ or $B$ is not invertible, is not invertible.

Comment: For the sake of a proof, you might want to check that $rank(AB) \leq rank(A)$ and $rank(AB) \leq rank(B)$.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of square matrices, all of a common size.  If we were to consider arbitrary matrices, even limited to ones with a defined product, the outcomes would not be so binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct. For $AB$ to be invertible $A,B$ must by invertible
as well.

Another way to see this is with determinants. The [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of a
matrix $A$ is denoted by $|A|$ and one can prove that $A$ is invertible
iff $|A|\neq0$.

We can also prove that 
$$
|AB|=|A|\cdot|B|
$$

which gives us the required result since for the multiplication of
two numbers to be non-zero so must both of the numbers be non-zero

Answer (score 3):

Case 1: $B$ is non-invertible.

There exists a non-zero vector $x$ such that $Bx=0$. It implies that $ABx=0$. So, $AB$ is non-invertible.

Case 2: $A$ is non-invertible and $B$ is invertible

There exists a non-zero vector $x$ such that $Ax=0$.

Since $B$ is invertible, take $y=B^{-1}x$ Clearly, $y$ is non-zero vector. Then, it follows,

$ABy=AB(B^{-1}x)=A(Ix)=Ax=0$. So, $AB$ is non-invertible.